# How to find mean of an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to iterate through the array and print the sum. But the output am getting is elements of the array.

```
 <p id="ans"></p>

    <script>
      var text = "the mean is ";
      function mean() {
        var sum = 0;
        var input = document.getElementsByName("values");
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          sum += input[i].value;
          text = text + sum;
        }

        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: try using `.reduce()` higher order function. There should be plenty of examples for getting the sum of the array, which then you could divide by the array length to get the mean :)

Comment: You are adding numbers multiple times to the string. They thus will be concatenated instead of numerically added. Make sure you sum to a numeric variable and only add it to the string when the math work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string values into integers and then sum it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
This is because in javascript if you adding a number to a string it will be casted to a string. For example:

```
0 + '1' + '2' // 012
```

But with parse int:

```
0 + parseInt('1') + parseInt('2') // 3
```

Or you can cast to int with a simple plus also:

```
0 + (+'1') + (+'2') // 3
```

Comment: This should help to you to fix your code.
Just modify the line: 

sum += parseInt(input[i].value);

Comment: When using `parseInt` [always specify an radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters)